# How to get Bokeh HTML visualizations to show on WordPress?

Tags: python, html, wordpress, bokeh

I have a Bokeh dashboard of visualization that I created in Python.  I have the HTML file saved.  When I open the file with my browser, it brings up my graphs (like it is supposed to!).  However, I am trying to display this dashboard on my WordPress site.  Pasting the HTML code into the HTML page option on WordPress doesn't work.  Does anyone know the trick for this, or can point me to the correct resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a shortcode to include the code. You can either save the html to a file and get the contents of it, or just copy & paste the code into your shortcode. Add something like this to your functions.php file:

```
function get_my_bokeh() {
    return file_get_contents( "http://www.example.com/path/to/bokeh.html" );
}
add_shortcode( 'print_bokeh', 'get_my_bokeh' );
```

/* OR */

```
function get_my_bokeh() { 
    ob_start(); ?>

    <!-- paste your HTML code here --> 

    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'print_bokeh', 'get_my_bokeh' );
```

Then add the shortcode `[print_bokeh]` to the text editor.

In both examples above you should clean out all of the  `<html>` `<head>` & `<body>` elements that make up a whole HTML document and just have the content.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are less familiar with php than with bokeh, let me expand Peter HvD's answer to get a reusable solution. The code in your theme's functions.php should be

```
function include_bokeh( $atts = array() ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'path' => '' 
    ), $atts));

    return file_get_contents( $path );
}
add_shortcode( 'show_bokeh', 'include_bokeh' );
```

And you call it in WordPress editor as

```
[show_bokeh path="http://www.example.com/path/to/bokeh.html"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to function and display, Bokeh plots require the ability to run JavaScript code. By default, WordPress disables JavaScript execution by scrubbing `<script>` tags from the output. You will have to enable JavaScript execution before Bokeh will work. Some methods are discussed here:

https://www.godaddy.com/garage/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/

Which method is most appropriate depends on your situation and preferences.